# Generate swagger.json spec for specific types

Tags: java, swagger

I have an artifact containing *only* POJO model classes designed to be serialized/deserialized using jackson objectmapper.

I am trying to generate a swagger model specification for these classes, but it seems like it is an unsupported use case (I have no REST endpoints, no spring, no jaxrs, etc.)

I have created a minimal example below of the input classes (using getters/setters from lombok).

```java
@Getters
@Setters
public class Location {
   String name;
   Coordinate coordinate;
}

@Getters
@Setters
public class Coordinate {
   double x;
   double y;
}
```

The end goal is to generate the swagger.json spec for these classes using maven. A great start would be something that can emit the required spec for only a single class, e.g., something to replace `swaggerSpecGenerator` below.

```java
var coordinateSpec = swaggerSpecGenerator(Coordinate.class);
```

Any pointers are happily received. :)

Comment: Swagger is based on openApi specifications, so it is meant for API not for POJO. I don't think in this case Swagger is right choice.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, we found https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator

It seems to be well aligned with out goals.

The following code outputs the schema for a specific class.

```java
SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(SchemaVersion.DRAFT_2019_09, OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON);
SchemaGeneratorConfig config = configBuilder.build();
SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(config);
JsonNode jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(YourClass.class);

System.out.println(jsonSchema.toString());
```

Comment: Disclaimer: creator of the mentioned victools/jsonschema-generator here. I just wanted to add, you should keep in mind that OpenAPI (swagger) is a superset of JSON schema. There are some additional properties supported in OpenAPI that you may have to add through individual configurations yourself (if you need them). But yes, JSON schema is the right tool for describing data structures (i.e. POJOs). I’m glad the library is of use to you.